My honda accord 2004 v6 always disengage while driving
not until i restart the car and engage it again .. i already drain the oil and put new oil it still disengages on motion ..  what can I do next

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Have you checked to see if there are any OBDII codes present? Are you sure the fluid is filled up to where it's supposed to be?

Lose/worn transmission linkages allowing the shift to neutral? You'll need someone capable of examining the PRNDL shift mechanism.
